# Log spring integration message lifecycle travelling through IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way how to log the lifecycle of the spring integration message?

e.g. given DSL IntegrationFlow

```
jmsFlowsUtils.jmsXmlInputFlow(queue)
    .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, firstFlow -> firstFlow
            .subFlowMapping(SomeClass.class.getName(), amEventFlow -> amEventFlow
                    .filter(...)
                    .transform(...)
                    .channel(...)
                    .handle(...)
            )
            .subFlowMapping(OtherClass.class.getName(), secondFlow -> secondFlow
                    .filter(...)
                    .transform(...)
                    .channel(...)
                    .handle(...)                    
            )
    )
    .get();
```

The log message would be a string containing EIP endpoint ids/names the message travelled through including timestamps

This would build the basis for some other tool to extract information from logs and present it to users in nice form (e.g. ELK stack might be used for that purpose: https://www.elastic.co/products)

Does anybody have any experience with this use-case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@EnableMessageHistory` to turn on message history tracking and that information is added to the headers as the message progresses through the flow.

See [Message History](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history).

You can use component name patterns to restrict the history tracking to certain components.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the answer. What about second part? Do you use any data interpreter which would print stats, graphs?

Comment: No, we don't that is out of Spring Integration scope. Consider something like Splunk to ingest logs and analyze them there: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-splunk

Comment: Looking at Splunk I can see there is outbound channel adapter, which means you will send messages there only if they can make it there (filters can prevent it). What if I want to log SI Message on every jump between EIP endpoints? Do I have to employ AOP advice and if yes, how would it look like? Thanks